# Непонятная работа async/await в aiohttp

Tags: python, async-await, aiohttp

Начинаю разбираться с асинхронным фреймворком aiohttp на Python.

Есть такой код (application.py):

```
application = web.Application()
...
application['db'] = aiomysql.connect(
    host=settings.DATABASE_HOST,
    user=settings.DATABASE_USER,
    password=settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    db=settings.DATABASE_NAME
)
...
application.router.add_route('GET', '/', MainController)
```

Далее - main_controller.py:

```
class MainController(web.View):

    @aiohttp_jinja2.template('main.html')
    async def get(self):

        sync_links = await get_sync_links(self.request.app)
        print(sync_links)
        print('ffffffffffffff')
        return {'sync_links': sync_links}
```

Далее - в database.py есть метод **get_sync_links**:

```
async def get_sync_links(application):

    connection_context = application['db']

    result = []

    async with connection_context as connection, connection.cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            await cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sync_links sl WHERE linkIsOn = 'y' ORDER BY sl.linkName ASC")
            result = await cursor.fetchall()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    connection.close()

    return result
```

Вот в чем вопрос - в коде

```
print(sync_links)
print('ffffffffffffff')
```

По идее должно быстрее выполниться `print('fffffffffff')`, а первым выводится `print(sync_links)`, но ведь у меня

```
sync_links = await get_sync_links(self.request.app)
```

а `print('fffffffffff')` по идее должно выполниться первым, быстрее, не дожидаясь получения данных из удаленной БД.

Может кто мне подскажет в чем моя ошибка? М.б. я что-то неправильно понимаю? Очень хотелось бы разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. В отличии от callback асинхронности, на время ожидания await запроса, выполнение функции приостанавливается. В этом и есть достоинство async/await — представить асинхронный код в привычном синхронном виде.

Comment: Спасибо. А я думал что приостанавливается именно тот код, который зависит от значения, возвращаемого в await (в нашем случае - sync_links = await get_sync_links(self.request.app)), то есть то что связано с ним - приостановится, а то что с ним не связано (print('ffffffffffffff')) - продолжится. А оказывается вот оно как... Допустим в C# кажется именно так как я описал, видимо в Питоне по-другому...

Comment: @DmitryDagadin, я вот в async-await не понимаю. А зачем функцию объявлять асинхронной `async`, чтобы после ее выполнение `await`'ом ждать?

Comment: Я так понимаю как только код дойдет до await, то управление передастся к следующей команде, которая должна была бы идти после выполнения этой функции, а выполнение функции продолжится после того, как строка с await будет выполнена. Типа как все что после await - это тот же коллбэк, только запись красивее, все равно что промисы в JS.